# how to display data (update from the staric hard coded values) in my app`s view controller`s label once the data is recieved from the server

Tags: ios, json, swift, uilabel

Hello Fellow Programmers.

I am new to swift programming and have researched on parsing json data.

I am building an app that uses authentication from the server.

Once the authentication is successful, i receive data that has all the details. the below details shows a glimpse of the data received in the console

```
         [ };
         troubleTicket =         {
        closedTicketsCount = 28395;
        openTroubleTicketsCount = 434;
        pendingWithCustomerTicketsCount = 602;
        resolvedTicketsCount = 3238;
        workInProgressTicketsCount = 380;
      }; 
        userDetails =         {
        errorDescription = "<null>";
        password = F5A2DC7EE0757DDF0C6E74A796D6E1C4785AD438;
        status = Success;]
```

that i have already hard coded in my first view

my view has the following components like

a) number of tickets resolved
b) number of tickets unresolved
c) pending tickets

[this image shows the labels that needs to be updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyZpy.png)

Can anyone help me as to how can i update the labels from the data I received ??

Do i have create a global class that stores all these and then update the labels??

Awaiting reply.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't provided enough information about your app's structure and how you set up your view controller. In general, though, I would say that you should have instance variables that hold the values that you display in your labels. In your init method, install starting values into those variables. In viewWillAppear, call a method to display the current values of those instance variables into your labels. Then, in your code that handles the JSON data call the method that displays the data to the labels again.

Comment: I would also recommend using https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON for swiftier json usage

Comment: I have tried as per your instruction. https://github.com/madmax994570/VodafoneApp_swift is where i have hosted the project.. Can u please have a look

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple places or controllers in the app which need to be updated than you should either use a delegate (@protocol) or notification( NSNotification ) which listen to this change and update their views respectively

You can have a global state variable in the app delegate and update its value on auth response. After this you can call either of delegate or notification for all the views to update their value.

Comment: Hi Amruta https://github.com/madmax994570/VodafoneApp_swift is where i have hosted the project.. Can u please have a look